# Ternary Operator - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php

```
$profilePic = isset( $userservice->getProfilePic($userid))      
              ?  filter($userservice->getProfilePic($userid)) 
              : '<img></img>';
```

Returns the error:

```
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please show us the declaration part of `filter()` and `var_dump` of `$userservice`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isset` only and exclusively works on variables. You do not need it for functions. Your ternary operator is fine.

See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Answer (score 9):

You can only use `isset` with variables, not with return values from functions, as `isset` is not a function, but a language construct.

*addendum*: There was a vote to [allow passing arbitrary expression arguments to `isset` and `empty`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/empty_isset_exprs), but finally `isset` was dropped from the final implementation.

Comment: in other words, a function result **is** set, no matter what

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. So, if I want to check if it's empty or not would `!empty` do the trick?

Comment: @Paul see my addendum. Right now, using `empty` will fail the same, but you can set `$profilePic = $userservice->getProfilePic($userid);` and then `!empty($profilePic) ? ... : ... ;`

Comment: Thanks @CarlosCampderrós. I'm trying to clean up some code and get rid of a few 'if` statements. My approach doesn't really seem to help me much :)

Comment: @Paul You need neither `isset` nor `empty`. A simple `== false` or `!` suffices.

Comment: @deceze - Wow, I'm dense tonight! :) That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve and looked right past it. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

try: "

```
$tempPic=$userservice->getProfilePic($userid);
         $profilePic = isset($tempPic ) ?  filter($userservicegetProfilePic($userid))  : '<img></img>';
```

"

Comment: This make no sense. It is always isset. Did you mean empty()?

Comment: `empty` is just as superfluous, you don't need either.